# How can I save and load multiple NumPy arrays at a single url?

Tags: python, numpy, url, pickle, loading

I would like to save and load several arrays to/from a file that is stored at a URL.

Here is how I have save the file:

```
    import numpy as np
    x=np.array([1,2,3])
    y=np.array([4,5,6])
    np.savez('./Test.npz',x=x,y=y)
```

Then I can successfully load the data from the local directory:

```
    data=np.load('./Test.npz', allow_pickle=True)
    print(data['x'],data['y'])
```

Here's how I try to load it from a URL that points to the same file:

```
ds=np.DataSource()
DataUrl='https://www.dropbox.com/s/1vpn5k3gt41nhtn/Test.npz'
DataFile = ds.open(DataUrl)
data = np.load(DataFile, allow_pickle=True)
```

I have also tried:

```
!wget -nc 'https://www.dropbox.com/s/lm5ejwf7wzo1e58/SpikeCounts112Neuron12Thetas.npz'
np.load(DataFile, allow_pickle=True)
```

In both cases, I get the following error:

```
----> 3 np.load(DataFile, allow_pickle=True)

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py in load(file, mmap_mode, allow_pickle, fix_imports, encoding)
    437         # If the file size is less than N, we need to make sure not
    438         # to seek past the beginning of the file
--> 439         fid.seek(-min(N, len(magic)), 1)  # back-up
    440         if magic.startswith(_ZIP_PREFIX) or magic.startswith(_ZIP_SUFFIX):
    441             # zip-file (assume .npz)

UnsupportedOperation: can't do nonzero cur-relative seeks
```

What am I doing wrong? What is a reasonable way to load multiple NumPy arrays from a single URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need to give `np.load` the filename, not the open `DataSource` object. This seems to work:

```py
import numpy as np

url = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/1vpn5k3gt41nhtn/Test.npz"
file = np.DataSource().open(url)
data = np.load(file.name)
```

Now `data['x']` is `array([1, 2, 3])` and `data['y']` is `array([4, 5, 6])`.

By the way, I learned something. I thought that to get a nice plain file out of Dropbox you had to stick `?raw=1` at the end of the URL. Turns out that's not true.

Last thing, kudos for setting up your question and example so nicely. Hardly anyone does that.